# (Java) how to read a text file block by block

Tags: java

suppose I have the following text file, how do I read each block of lines separated by 2 empty lines in Java?

Thanks!

```
Reference Type:  Journal Article
Record Number: 153
Author: Yang, W. and Kang, J.
Year: 2005
Title: Acoustic comfort evaluation in urban open public spaces
Journal: Applied Acoustics
Volume: 66
Issue: 2
Pages: 211-229
Short Title: Acoustic comfort evaluation in urban open public spaces
ISSN: 0003682X
DOI: 10.1016/j.apacoust.2004.07.011
'File' Attachments: internal-pdf://0633242026/Acoustic comfort evaluation in urban open public spaces.pdf


Reference Type:  Thesis
Record Number: 3318
Author: Wienold, Jan
Year: 2009
Title: Daylight glare in offices
University: Fraunhofer Institute for Solar Energy Systems ISE
Thesis Type: PhD Dissertation
Short Title: Daylight glare in offices
URL: http://publica.fraunhofer.de/eprints/urn:nbn:de:0011-n-1414579.pdf
'File' Attachments: internal-pdf://2172014641/Daylight glare in offices.pdf
```

It seems that answering questions in this forum is quite picky ... I think its really not necessary. Nevertheless, here's my try via Processing, a programming environment built on top of Java:

```
import java.util.*;
String fileName = "";
String line;
BufferedReader br;

void setup(){
  fileName = "My_EndNote_Library_2014-07-04.txt";
  br = createReader(fileName);  
}

void draw(){
  try {
    line = br.readLine();
    println(line);
    println();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    line = null;
  }

   if (line == null) {
    // Stop reading because of an error or file is empty
    noLoop();  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since data (rows) of each block is not the same you can do something like this. Using `\n\n` as delimiter for each block and `\n` for each line

```
import java.io.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {   
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.txt"));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while (true) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            if (line == null) break;
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        }       

        String[] blocks = sb.toString().split("\n\n");

        for (String block : blocks) {
            block = block.trim();
            // block - individual block from file
            String[] data = block.split("\n");
            for (String d : data) {
                // d - individual line of block 
            }   
        }   
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two flaws in accepted answer though essence of logic is correct that you don't need any complex regex etc ,

1.Code is not OS neutral since `\n` is hard coded

2.Second, since a `\n` is added after each line so there would be three `\n` chars between two blocks instead of two `\n` chars ( two from two empty lines and one extra from previous block ) . Splitting on two chars will also work but **block-1** on wards would contain an extra new line at the beginning so you might require trim .

Code is assuming that file is on class path & not on disk.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class ReferenceType {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ReferenceType app = new ReferenceType();
        String allLines = null;
        String[] blocks = null;
        String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try {
            allLines = app.getFileAsString(lineSeparator);
            blocks = allLines.split(lineSeparator+lineSeparator+lineSeparator);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private String getFileAsString(String lineSeparator) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
        Path path = Paths.get(this.getClass().getResource("ReferenceType.txt").toURI());
        String textLine = null;
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(path)) {
            while ((textLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    builder.append(textLine);
                    builder.append(lineSeparator);
            }
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }
}
```